# How to connect to AWS RDS using Golang?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, go

I am trying to connect to the AWS RDS using the following code. I got help from [this website](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Go.html) but when I executed this code, it gave me the following error.

**Error**

```
panic: failed to create authentication token: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, request canceled, context deadline exceeded
```

**Code**

```
func Connect() (db *sql.DB) {
    db_user := middleware.LoadEnvVariable("DB_USER")
    // db_password := middleware.LoadEnvVariable("DB_PASSWORD")
    db_host := "database endpoint string"
    db_db := middleware.LoadEnvVariable("DB_DB")
    dbEndpoint := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", db_address, 3306)
    region := "ap-south-1a"

    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        panic("configuration error: " + err.Error())
    }
    authenticationToken, err := auth.BuildAuthToken(context.TODO(), dbEndpoint, region, db_user, cfg.Credentials)
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to create authentication token: " + err.Error())
    }
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s)/%s?tls=true&allowCleartextPasswords=true", db_user, authenticationToken, dbEndpoint, db_db)

    dbbase, err := sql.Open("mysql", s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return dbbase
}
```

Comment: I am waiting for your answer.

Comment: Two days are passed and I am still waiting for the answer.

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow Answers are provided by normal people, just like you. It is not anyone's job to answer questions and you are not paying for this service. Saying things like "I am waiting for your answer" could be considered rude/offensive. I notice that you have asked many question on StackOverflow, but you have not volunteered any Answers. You might consider helping other people by answering questions on topics that you know well.